# parallel programming - I need some clarifications

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, c#-4.0, asynchronous

Okay , let me try to put it in sentences ...

Lets consider an example, 
where I create an `async` method and call it with `await` keyword, 
As far as my knowledge tells me,

1. The main thread will be released
2. In a separate thread, async method will start executing
3. Once it is executed, The pointer will resume from last position It left in main thread.

**Question 1 :** Will it come back to main thread or it will be a new thread ?

**Question 2:** Does it make any difference if the async method is CPU bound or network bound ? If yes, what ?

### The important question

**Question 3 :** Assuming that is was a CPU bound method, What did I achieve? I mean - main thread was released, but at the same time, another thread was used from thread pool. what's the point ?

Comment: One correction to your process, The process goes 1) The main thread executes the function up to the `await` keyword, at some point before that a new thread was started and is doing work in the back ground. 2) The main thread stops processing the function and starts processing other messages in the message queue, 3) once the background function completes it puts a new message in the message queue that restarts the `async` function leaving off where the `await` keyword was.

Comment: Answering question 3, the point is that your main thread usually perform a set of instruction which aren't strictly related to your methods (eg. rendering the UI), so allocating another thread to perform CPU intensive computations will allow your "software" to avoid freezing

Comment: Ok, so apart from making the ui more responsive, there no other advantage. I thought I am getting an extra thread for free for a while.

Comment: `async`/`await` by itself have little to do with threads. Simply adding `async` to a method signature will not change behavrior of the code (and definitely not create extra threads) unless this method will start using real async methods and calling them with await.

Comment: @Yosi I am sorry. They are all related from my perspective.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks. Will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @BilalFazlani - SO is a Q&A site, i see 5 question marks in your question, what you really want, is to cover an entire topic, and not to ask a specific question..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`async` does not start a new thread. Neither does `await`. I recommend you read my [`async` intro post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and follow up with the resources at the bottom.

`async` is not about parallel programming; it's about *asynchronous* programming. If you need parallel programming, then use the Task Parallel Library (e.g., PLINQ, `Parallel`, or - in very complex cases - raw `Task`s).

For example, you could have an `async` method that does I/O-bound operations. There's no need for another thread in this scenario, and none will be created.

If you do have a CPU-bound method, then you can use `Task.Run` to create an awaitable `Task` that executes that method on a thread pool thread. For example, you could do something like `await Task.Run(() => Parallel...);` to treat some parallel processing as an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @StephenClearly I was very surporised to know that parallel and asyncronous are different! What exactly is the difference if i may ask

Comment: @BilalFazlani: "Asynchronous" (in the sense of `async`) means that you are starting an operation that will complete at a later time. "Parallel" means that you are spinning up multiple threads to do CPU-bound processing. As noted, `async` (and `await`) do not spin up background threads; they are asynchronous but not parallel.

Comment: @BilalFazlani: The definitions I'm using are the ones that IMO make the most sense; they're quite literal. It's not uncommon to see someone use the term "asynchronous" for executing something on a thread pool thread, or the term "parallel" for doing more than one thing at a time (e.g., `await`). But I discourage these uses because we need clearer terminology.

Comment: last one - `you are starting an operation that will complete at a later time` .. WHEN EXACTLY ?

Comment: @BilalFazlani: Whenever it completes. If it's an HTTP request, it's when you get the response. If it's a parallel computation on the thread pool, it's when the computation is done.

Answer (score 4):

1. Execution of the caller and `async` method will be entirely on the current thread. `async` methods don't create a new thread and using `async/await` does not actually create additional threads. Instead, thread completions/callbacks are used with a synchronization context and suspending/giving control (think Node.js style programming). However, when control is issued to or returns to the `await` statement, it **may** end up being on a different completion thread (this depends on your application and some other factors).
2. Yes, it will run slower if it is CPU or Network bound. Thus the `await` will take longer.
3. The benefit is not in terms of threads believe it or not... Asynchronous programming does not necessarily mean multiple threads. The benefit is that you can continue doing other work that doesn't require the `async` result, before waiting for the `async` result... An example is a web server HTTP listener thread pool. If you have a pool of size 20 then your limit is 20 concurrent requests... If all of these requests spend 90% of their time waiting on database work, you could `async/await` the database work and the time during which you `await` the database result callback will be freed... The thread will return to the HTTP listener thread pool and another user can access your site while the original one waits for the DB work to be done, upping your total limit.

It's really about freeing up threads that wait on externally-bound and slow operations to do other things while those operations execute... Taking advantage of built-in thread pools.

Comment: `await` does not necessarily return to the same thread. That only happens if the thread is a UI thread.

Comment: Well it does not have to be a UI Thread either, it just needs to have [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) not return `null`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: [A `SynchronizationContext` does not have a 1-to-1 relationship with a thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/09/another-synchronizationcontext-gotcha.html) (link is to my blog). One common example is the ASP.NET SyncCtx which will *not* return the method to the same thread. A less common example is if `Current` was set to `new SynchronizationContext()` - it would not be `null`, but would not use a particular thread, either.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the async part could be some long-running job, e.g. running a giant database query over the network, downloading a file from the internet, etc.